# Alterar titulo por ícone

Tags: html, ionic, ionic3

Ainda estou aprendendo sobre Ionic. Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar o título dos guias por um ícone ou uma imagem personalizada.

[image: Page 1,2,3,4]

HTML

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>empty</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content >
    <ion-segment  class="SwipedTabs-tabs"  >
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="IngoreMe" (click)="selectTab(i)"
        [ngClass]='{ "SwipedTabs-activeTab" : ( this.SwipedTabsSlider  && ( this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() === i || (  tabs.length -1 === i&& this.SwipedTabsSlider.isEnd()))) }' >
          {{tab}}
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>

      <!-- here is our dynamic line  "indicator"-->
      <div id='indicator' class="SwipedTabs-indicatorSegment" [ngStyle]="{'width.%': (100/this.tabs.length)}"></div>

      <ion-slides #SwipedTabsSlider  (ionSlideDrag)="animateIndicator($event)"
                  (ionSlideWillChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()"
                  (ionSlideDidChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()"
                  (pan)="updateIndicatorPosition()"
                  [pager]="false"
            >
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Page 1 </h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Page 2 </h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Page 3 </h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Page 4 </h1>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

TS

```
   import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

    /**
     * Generated class for the EmptyPage page.
     *
     * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
     * Ionic pages and navigation.
     */

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-empty',
      templateUrl: 'empty.html',
    })
    export class EmptyPage {

      @ViewChild('SwipedTabsSlider') SwipedTabsSlider: Slides ;

      SwipedTabsIndicator :any= null;
      tabs:any=[];


      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.tabs=["page1","page2","page3","page4"];
      }
      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.SwipedTabsIndicator = document.getElementById("indicator");
      }

      selectTab(index) {    
        this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(100*index)+'%,0,0)';
        this.SwipedTabsSlider.slideTo(index, 500);
      }

      updateIndicatorPosition() {
          // this condition is to avoid passing to incorrect index
        if( this.SwipedTabsSlider.length()> this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex())
        {
            this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() * 100)+'%,0,0)';
        }

        }

      animateIndicator($event) {
        if(this.SwipedTabsIndicator)
            this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + (($event.progress* (this.SwipedTabsSlider.length()-1))*100) + '%,0,0)';
      }

    }
```

Comment: Não seria <ion-slide>  <img src="">  </ion-slide> ?

Comment: Então..  adicionando como você mencionou, fica apenas uma imagem dentro do conteúdo. Eu quero por onde está Page 1 Page 2 Page 3 Page 4 um ícone no lugar deles..

[![está assim][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G47e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para icones use a tag `<ion-icon></ion-icon>` e para imagem use `<ion-img width="80" height="80" src="..."></ion-img>` remova o {{tab}} e adicione a tag icon

```
    <ion-segment  class="SwipedTabs-tabs"  >
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="IngoreMe" (click)="selectTab(i)"
    [ngClass]='{ "SwipedTabs-activeTab" : ( this.SwipedTabsSlider  && ( this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() === i || (  tabs.length -1 === i&& this.SwipedTabsSlider.isEnd()))) }' >
        <ion-icon name="analytics"></ion-icon>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

o melhor jeito de fazer isso caso seja estático seria adicionando o `ion-segment-button` um a um no seu codigo ele ta gerando dinamicamente pelo ngFor e pegando os valores do `this.tab` assim ele gera 4 `ion-segment-button`se você adiconar um quinto tab vera que ele tbm criara um novo botão. Exemplo de icons estáticos:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="icons" color="secondary">
  <ion-segment-button value="camera">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="bookmark">
    <ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: Olha na imagem como gostaria que ficasse
[![Ícones onde está a seta azul e nao vermelha][1]][1]


    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S20Dq.png

Comment: desculpa nao tinha entendido, editei o codigo tente colocar o icon dentro da tag <h1></h1>

Comment: Continua adicionando o ícone dentro da página e não como desejado

Comment: @FelipeXST tente adicionar um style com background-image  em h1

Comment: pode me dizer  como exatamente eu faço isso? estou tentando de todas as formas conseguir isso mas ainda tenho bastante dificuldades.

Comment: <h1 style="background-image: url("sua url");"></h1>

Comment: obrigado por tentar ajudar, mas ainda não está indo :(

Comment: fiz novas edições na resposta de uma olhada novamente

Comment: Muito obrigado, exatamente isso que eu queria. Fiz como você disse, adicionei um a um, no final consegui o que queria.  Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: desculpa isso, mas o seguinte está acontecendo:

[![múltiplas][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCfJu.png

Comment: se você colocou um a um retire o ng for da tag ion-segment-button se a reposta funcionou clique no botão pra escolher como resposta certa obg

Comment: ainda não funcionou.  Acredito que seja alguma coisa nesse ngFor, quando eu deixo ele como comentário ele funciona, mas as abas deslizantes nao funcionam. está ficando como na ultima imagem que postei acima

Comment: tentou igual o primeiro codigo? apenas com a imagem sem o {{tabs}}

Answer (score 0):

em .ts  consigo editar o titulo, onde está:   "
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.tabs=["page1","page2","page3","page4"]; "

Mas não sei como a partir daqui ( se for por aqui ) que eu altero para um ícone, ou uma imagem. Caso alguém entenda o que eu desejo e souber algo que possa ajudar, ficaria muito agradecido. :D